# How do I make 1 empty partition out of an external USB disk?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-format, diskutil

I made a mistake with `dd` and now my external USB disk looks as follows:

```
$ diskutil list

(... output ...)

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS BLA                     268.4 MB   disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         1.6 GB     disk2s2
```

Now when I open the disk in Disk Utility, it only shows 268.4 MB, not the full 4 TB it should be. I can't seem to fix it in Disk Utility, but I'm sure it can be done using the command line?

The output of `gpt` is as follows:

```
~$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk2
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1        8191         
        8192      524288      1  MBR part 175
      532480     3080192      2  MBR part 131
     3612672  7810357248
```

I sense that the solution is something like overwriting the whole disk with zeroes using `dd` and `/dev/zero`, but after my previous failure I am now scared that I brick the disk permanently.

Comment: What goes wrong with *Disk Utility*? Select the drive not the partition and you should be able to erase it.

Comment: In Disk Utility, do you have Devices shown, or just Volumes? View Menu. once you can see Devices, format the Device rather than the Volume.

Comment: If I erase in Disk Utility, I can fill in a new file system format, but then I only get back the 268.4 MB partition in that chosen new file system. I cannot get the 4TB back. The "partition" option in Disk Utility is greyed out (maybe because 268.4 MB is too small?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will erase all data that currently exists on the USB drive:

1. Remove your USB drive.
2. Open Disk Utility.
3. In the menu bar, click [View] > [Show All Devices].
4. Insert your USB drive. You should see the drive appear in the sidebar in Disk Utility as an item whose name is the manufacturer name and model name/number of the drive. Click this item to select it.
5. Click [Erase] in the top bar.
6. Enter a name of your choosing.
7. For the format, choose "MS-DOS (FAT)".
8. For the scheme, choose "GUID Partition Table". This is required since your drive exceeds 2TiB in size.
9. Click [Security Options...], move the slider to "Fastest", then click "OK".
10. Click [Erase].

---

macOS will enforce the creation of a 200MiB EFI System Partition on GPT-formatted drives. If you want to claim this space, you can either:

- format the drive using another tool of another OS (e.g. Windows Disk Management, GParted for Linux); or
- use the `gpt` command (or an equivalent like [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)) to manually create a single partition which spans the whole drive, which you will then need to format with a filesystem, e.g. create a FAT32 filesystem using `newfs_msdos`. If you want to create an EXT filesystem, the `mkfs.ext?` commands (e.g. `mkfs.ext4`) can be obtained via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) by running `brew install e2fsprogs`.

Comment: I'll try this later tonight. Is there any way to make the whole drive `ext4` on Mac? (Or via Ubuntu, I could spin up a VirtualBox)

Comment: There is no native tool to creat EXT filesystems, but you can install `e2fsprogs` (e.g. with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), just run `brew install e2fsprogs`) and then you will have the `mkfs.ext4` command at your fingertips. Use the `gpt`/`gdisk` method to create a single partition, then `mkfs.ext4` to format the partition with an EXT4 filesystem.

Comment: Since you asked "or via Ubuntu?", you should look at GParted, which is a popular, powerful GUI partition editor for Linux. It comes pre-installed on the Ubuntu Live ISOs in case you need to use it in a rescue situation or to format your disks before installation, but it isn't present by default on a full Ubuntu installation made using such an ISO.

Comment: @Jivan Pal: You assume the sector size is 512 bytes. If this is true, then there is a 2TiB limit when using a MBR partition table. Often 4 TB drives use a 4096 byte sector size. In such cases, the limit would be 16 TiB.